# Why does this function in Java doesn't affect the result?

Tags: java, arrays, function, methods

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        reverse(list);
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(list[i] + " ");
        }
   }

   public static void reverse(int[] list) {
       int[] newList = new int[list.length];

       for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
           newList[i] = list[list.length - 1 - i];
       }

       list = newList;
   }
}
```

When I run this program the answer is 1 2 3 4 5. This 'reverse' method is called on line 4th.

Comment: I don't know java, but maybe `list = reverse(list);`?

Comment: Yea! That means I will have to return the 'newList' and change the 'void' to 'int[]', just like others mentioned. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to `return` the new list, not to modify the parameter reference, because it's only method-scoped.

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        list = reverse(list);
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(list[i] + " ");
        }
   }

   public static int[] reverse(int[] list) {
       int[] newList = new int[list.length];

       for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
           newList[i] = list[list.length - 1 - i];
       }

       return newList;
   }
}
```

Comment: Accept my answer, if you think it was the most useful, please :)

Comment: Vote up, so I can lift up my restrictions :)

Answer (score 3):

```
list = newList;
```

You just changed the local parameter to refer to a new array instance.

That does not affect the caller's variable, which still refers to the original array instance that you passed.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are passing `list` by value. i.e. the line `list = newList` has no effect on the caller. In Java, everything is passed by value.

To do what you want, change your function to

```
public static int[] reverse(int[] list)
```

and at the end of your function.

```
return newList;
```

instead of

```
list = newList;
```

More formally, the reference to the array is passed by value. When you reassign list = newList you are making the reference point to a different array. But the reference is unchanged in the caller and so therefore points at the original array.

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense to me now!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Java parameter passing is pass-by-value.  The last statement of `reverse` is this:

```
    list = newList;
```

Unfortunately, since `list` is a parameter (and is passed by value), this assignment does not affect the value of `list` in the `main` method.

To get the `reverse` method to work properly either:

- change it to *return* the reversed list (and assign the result to `list` in `main`), or
- change it to assign the cells of `list` from the corresponding cells of `newList`.

(Incidentally, if you are going to update `list` in place, you can do it without a separate `newList` array.)

---

In response to this comment:

> The book that I am reading says that an array is passed by reference and whatever happens to the array in a method will affect the original array in the main method. Or maybe I interpreted it wrong!

Either the book is wrong, or you misunderstood it.  (Probably the latter, I suspect.)  All types (that is **all types**) in Java are passed by value, and returned by value.

The slightly confusing thing is that in the case of reference types, the value that is passed or returned is the object's reference.  This leaves room for misunderstanding the terminology (or for a book to be a bit sloppy) but ...

> *"passing **by** reference"*

... and ...

> *"passing **a** reference"*

... do NOT mean the same thing.

(In hindsight, Gosling et al's decision to call Java object pointers "references" is a source of confusion for new Java programmers.  OTOH, there would have been a different kind confusion for programmers transitioning from C and C++ if they had stuck with the old term "pointers".)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, Java's passing a reference to your array by value.  That is, the reference `reverse` is modifying isn't the caller's version, but a copy of it made just for this call.  The caller will never see the reassignment.

The end result is that you can modify the array all you want, but you can't *replace* it with a different array in a way the caller will see.  There's no way to do that in Java, short of creating a wrapper class.

You could achieve the result you're looking for by copying the new array into the old one when you're done.  ie: Rather than

```
list = newList;
```

do

```
System.arraycopy(newList, 0, list, 0, list.length);
```

You could also reverse it in place, if you're sure you always want it to modify the original array:

```
public static void reverse(int[] list) {
    for (int i = 0, j = list.length - 1; i < j; ++i, --j) {
         int temp = list[i];
         list[i] = list[j];
         list[j] = temp;
    }
}
```

This avoids creating an object you're just going to throw away.

But if you foresee ever wanting just a reversed *copy* of the array, and not always modifying the one you're given, you'd do better to return the new array instead and let the caller decide what to do with it.